# How to access data from a return partial view along with JSON data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I use:

```
$.get('/Main/Sub', { id: id }, function(response, text, XMLHttpRequest){
    // returns the page
});
```

C# controller:

```
public ActionResult Sub(int id){
    // code
return PartialView(ViewNames.Sub, theViewModel);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is return the partial ( which it does ) along with view model data. Currently there isn't a way for me to decipher the data being passed back in the theViewModel, I can only read the html page being returned. How can I access the data as well?

Comment: You would have to write JavaScript around your HTML response to extract the data out of it. Alternatively, if you did not want the HTML to be returned in first place, you could use something like $.getJSON to just get the data back

Comment: Also, if you intended to pass just the data back from controller, you could use PartialView's overload that just passes back object without view

Comment: could be null the model, or during the model's binding exeption too?

Answer (score 0):

Your partial view could have a bunch of hidden fields:

```
@* Can target directly or use classes to target hidden fields in JS *@
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID, new { @class = "id-field" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "name-field" })
```

Or your partial view could have data attributes on it:

```
<div data-row="{@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)}"
```

or

```
<div data-id="@Model.ID" data-name="@Model.Name"
```

These are a few approaches.  Alternatively, return JSON, and bind the JSON to a template like these:

- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview
- https://handlebarsjs.com/
- https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender
- and more - I've been out of the templating arena for a while...